# Identifying transient errors in NSURLConnection

Tags: objective-c, error-handling, foundation

**Scenario:**

I am trying to asynchronously retrieve a file from a cloud storage provider (Azure Blob-Storage or Amazon S3) using a NSURLConnection.

My idea is to implement the NSURLConnectionDelegate:

```
-(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    // Check if the error code is transient 
    if([self checkIsTransientError:error])
    {
        // Create a new NSUrlConnection and re-try the call.

    }
    else
    {
        // The error is permanent, notify the UI that the file isn't there

    } 
}
```

Of course there will be a lot of other nice tricks in my code, like max number of retries and exponential back-off... but I leave the pseudo-code as simple as it's needed to illustrate my question.

**Question:**

What error codes are considered transient?

So far I came up with a (short) list of possibilities:

- HTTP Status 500
- No network connectivity (because of bad network)
- Timeout
- CannotFindHost (DNSError)

**Update:** I finally found the documentation for all the massive number of possible error codes defined in the NSURLError

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/URL_Loading_System_Error_Codes

So I'm now having a long read so I can decide which of them should be considered as transient for my app.

**Note:** I don't want to include AFNetworking or other nice framework on the project just for the sake of not having to make this transient check.

Comment: Why don't you use `NSURLSession`? `NSURLConnection` is deprecated from iOS9

Comment: @LucaD I didn't know it existed, neither that NSURLConnection is about to be deprecated (rookie error, I know) so I will switch my implementation to NSURLSession. Kudos for the advice